# many to many relationship in mysql have to be the foreign keys the primary keys from both tables connections tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Lets says that I have an order table and item table :

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists ORDERS (
    ORDERID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ORDERTYPE VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    ShippedTime VARCHAR(40),
    ORDERDATE DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (ORDERID),
);
CREATE TABLE if not exists ITEM(
    ITEMID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NAME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    PRICE INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (PRICE > 0),
    PRIMARY KEY (ITEMID)
);
```

and the relation between the both tables will be existof :

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists EXISTOF (
  ORDERID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ITEMID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (ORDERID) REFERENCES ORDERS(ORDERID)  ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (ITEMID) REFERENCES ITEM(ITEMID)  ON DELETE CASCADE,
  PRIMARY KEY (ORDERID,ITEMID)
);
```

The explanation should be for each order has multiple item and each item belongs to many orders.
If I do like this it will not be work because the ids are primary keys and I can't insert for specific order multiple item and also it can not items belongs to multiple order.
Does anyone have any recommendation how to do that?

Comment: PRIMARY KEY (ORDERID,ITEMID) is fine if an order can contain only one itemid amongst many items , if an order can contain the same itemid more than once in an order  then a key (ie not a primary or unique  key) would be appropriate - in either case the order (and item) has to be created before the junction table

Comment: So its possible to don't make the orderid and itemid not primary keys in the existof table ? As i know in many to many relation should be new table created which its primary keys the both ids or its wrong ?

Comment: It's up to you.  You can define a junction table with a unique junction table ID and a unique index with order ID and order item ID,  or you can create a compound primary key with order ID and order item ID.  Either way has advantages and disadvantages.  My preference is that every table has a single unique auto-incrementing ID and all reference IDs are indexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Existof Table is not flexible enough.  The way most order processing systems deal with this situation is to add a column, which we can call Quantity, to the Existof table.  The default value is 1,  but other quantities can be put in as well.

So if a given order wants to order say 5 reams of paper,and ream of paper in a product,  the entry for this item in Existof will have a quantity of 5.

This assumes that all 5 reams are interchangeable, and therefore described by the same data.  If some of the paper reams are of different colors,  than they ought to be different products.

Comment: But how to let the same order have another products (not only paper), because the orderid in existof is primary key and can't be duplicate?

Comment: orderid in existof is NOT a primary key.  The combination oderid, itemid is the primary key.  BTW,  do you have a master product table?  Is this called ITEM?  That's a confusing name.

Answer (score 0):

Create an intermediate table OrderItems with foreign keys item_id and order_id. There are other options but this is the easiest way I find to break down many-many relationships!

Answer (score 0):

"... have to be ..." -- no.  `FOREIGN KEYs` are never "required".

A FK provides three things:

- A dynamic check that there is a matching element.  This is useful as an integrity check on the data, but is not mandatory.
- An `INDEX` to make the above check significantly faster.  Manually specifying an `INDEX` is just as good.  Anyway, a `PRIMARY KEY` is an index.
- "Casscading delete, etc".  This is an option that few schemas use, or even need.

There are 3 main types of "relations" between tables:

1:1 -- But why bother having two tables?  The columns could simply be in a single table.  (There are exceptions.)

1:many -- (This sounds like "many items in one order"??)  That is implemented by simply having `order_id` in the `Items` table.  (And index that column.)  Optionally, it can be a FK.  Others call the table `OrderItems`.  And it links to a `Products` table.

many:many -- This is when you need an extra table with (usually) exactly two columns, namely ids into the other two tables.  (Eg, Student vs class)  Each column could be an FK, but the optimal indexes are `PRIMARY KEY(a_id, b_id)` and `INDEX(b_id, a_id)`.  The FKs would see that you already have indexes starting with a_id and b_id, so it would not create an extra index.  Do not have "a unique junction table ID"; it is less efficient than the PK I suggest here.  (More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Back to your proposed design.  I suggest that "item" implies the product and quantity of that product and the price charged at that time.  Hence it needs to be 1:many.  And that "product" is what you are thinking of.  Please change the table name so I am not confused.

Now, another issue... Price.  Is the price fixed forever?  Or is the price going to be different for today's Orders than for yesterday's?  Again, the Item and Price are tied to *one* Order.  There may be a Price on the Product table, and that may be "current_price", which gets used when creating new Orders.

`ShippedTime VARCHAR(40)` -- Perhaps should be `DATETIME`?